# Django fixtures, loading in large amounts of data

Tags: django, django-fixtures

So I have two 200mb JSON files. The first one takes 1.5 hours to load, and the second which (which makes a bunch of many-to-many relationships models with the first), takes 24+ hours (since there's no updates via the console, I have no clue if it was still going or if it froze, so I stopped it).

Since the loaddata wasn't working that well, I wrote my own script that loaded the data while also outputting what's been recently saved into the db, but I noticed the speed of the script (along with my computer) decayed the longer it went. So I had to stop the script -> restart my computer -> resume at the section of data where I left off, and that would be faster than running the script throughout. This was a tedious process since it took roughly 18 hrs with me restarting the computer every 4 hours to get all the data fully loaded.

I'm wondering if there is a better solution for loading in large amounts of data?

EDIT: I realized there's an option to load in raw SQL, so I may try that, although I need to brush up on my SQL.

Answer (score 4):

When you're loading large amounts of data, writing your own custom script is generally the fastest. Once you've got it loaded in once, you can use your databases import/export options, which will generally be very fast (ex, `pgdump`).

When you are writing your own script, though, two things which will *drastically* speed things up:

1. Loading data inside a transaction. By default the database is likely in autocommit mode, which causes an expensive commit after each insert. Instead, make sure that you `begin` a transaction before you insert anything, then `commit` it afterwards (importantly, though, don't forget to commit; nothing sucks like spending three hours importing data, only to realize you forgot to commit it).
2. Bypassing the Django ORM and use raw `INSERT` statements. There is some computational overhead to the ORM, and bypassing it will make things faster.

Comment: Well, I've tried loading in data with manual commits and transactions and it's still rather slow. Guess I'm going to have to go the raw sql route.